# Class/global function declarations C++

Tags: c++, function

Please help - what is a global function and what it is used for and when? the syntax is (the simplest one):

```
int Sum (Class_name h) {...}
```

Comment: Are you in a classroom being asked this question?

Comment: It's a class/function you can access at the global scope in your program.

Comment: @Kitet If I was the asker I would have given up by now …

Comment: I didn't mean to be mean :D but googling would give immediate answer in this case. Couldn't help myself.

Answer (score 4):

In C++ "global functions" should be defined in a .cpp file, and declared in a .h file.

For instance

Sum.h:

```
int Sum(int a, int b); // declaration (prototype)
```

Sum.cpp:

```
int Sum(int a, int b) // definition
{
    return a + b;
}
```

Now if you want to use the Sum function in another .cpp file simply add `#include "Sum.h"` and use the function.

AnotherModule.cpp:

```
#include "Sum.h"

void MyOtherFunction()
{
    int var = Sum(3,4);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sorry, but I'll try to be more clear with my question. Mentioned syntax is declaration of the global function but i don't know where it should stand and when it is used - i mean this particular syntax. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3):

A global function (in C++) is a function which is accessible anywhere in the code.
It's a heritage of the C programming language. For people who began with a language like java, it can looks strange because it's not in a class, but it is a little like a public static method, because you don't need any object to call it

So, You can use this function anywhere... (just to be sure it has been declared (see note) before, like in a header file.) It's better to enclose them in a namespace to avoid name conflicts with other libraries and to organize your code but C++ allow to declare it in global scope.

You could use it when there is no relation with any object, or when it's a function used only in the file where it is declared... for example, if you want an initialization out of the main, or to an operation you don't want to put into a class etc.
There is no strict rules about that... It's most as you feel it ;)

Note : 
"Declared" = you tell the compiler that a function `int Sum (Class_name h)` exists, so he won't insult you "You're function has not been declared"

"Defined" = you code your function. it's needed to tell the compiler what this function do example:
`int sum(Class h){
   return h.a + h.b;
}`

You need to define your function (not "#define" here ;) ) one time in a .c/.cpp and use the declaration in a .h to use it (unless you are editing the .cpp where the function is defined, and in this case this function needs to be above)

Comment: Do you mean the scope for the function in anywhere in the program and that's why this is "little like static methods"?

Comment: I said "little like a static method" because you don't need any abject to call it. I 'll add "like a PUBLIC static method" because It's more that in fact, because these function can be called anywhere, just as I said. It's often in global scope when the programmer doesn't want to associate it with a class or a namespace, but it's better to organize your code so I advise you to avoid that in final code, and to put it in a namespace. (http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/ for more information)